# http request via https

Tags: nginx, https, http

Here is a scenario - http request are sent from monitoring client to an address like https://something.com:9443 which on the other end is (though) handled by nginx configured only as http server. If the nginx is switched to https only it rejects the http requests.

Maybe it's trival but I'm not sure what's happenening there, more specifically, is sending http request via https address somehow encrypted or in this case (since on the other side is only http server) it's pure cosmetics?

Comment: sending `https://` request to a http-only server will fail. sending `http://` request to a https-only server will fail.

Comment: ok, but it definately does not fail, moreover if you change the address to http it does not work since some internal security devices on the way want it to be https

Comment: maybe the root cause here is that aforementioned nginx is configured as forwarder only, the final destination is http server, taking into account what @AlexD said it looks like the https in the address does not matter, the traffic is still regular http, am I right?

Comment: only on Nginx is not possible, your scenario is complex you need to try to check proxy over Nginx or iptables to convert some request to another